# How to Create an Expression tree for .Where(x => x.<deep property>.Select(y => y.id).Intersect(List<int>).Any())

Tags: c#, select, intersect, any

I'm creating a method that receives a `Queryable<T>` source, a string with a property name/path (could be a deep property for example `"TrParent.DataTypes"` to achieve this `x => x.TrParent.DataTypes`) and `Enumerable<int>` which holds the values I need to intersect.

Basically I come from the need to create the following query dynamically (I mean `<DT_Det_Tr>` and  `TrParent.DataTypes` being know only at runtime, in the example `DT_Det_Tr` is not a type it is a class):

```
var _vals = new List<int>();
var res = dbContext.Set<DT_Det_Tr>()
                .Where
                (x => x.TrParent.DataTypes
                    .Select(t => t.Id)
                        .Intersect(_vals)
                            .Any()
                );
```

Please keep in mind that the preceding query is just an example of what I need to achieve dynamically, what I really need is an expression tree that creates a predicate like the one shown above but using a dynamic type and with the deep navigation property specified within a string.

So, I'm using this function to create the expression for the deep property:

```
private static LambdaExpression CreateDelegateExpression<T>(out Type resultingtype, string property, string parameterName = "x")
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(type, parameterName);
    Expression expr = param;
    foreach (string prop in property.Split('.'))
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop);
        expr = Expression.Property(expr, pi);
        type = pi.PropertyType;
    }
    Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), type);
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, expr, param);
    resultingtype = type;
    return lambda;
}
```

And here is what I have so far for my function:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Intersect<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string property, IEnumerable<int> value)
{
    //List of ids
    var _value = Expression.Constant(value);

    //Get delegate expression to the deep property and it's inner type
    Type type = null;
    var lambda = CreateDelegateExpression<T>(out type, property, "x");
    var enumtype = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    ParameterExpression tpe = Expression.Parameter(enumtype, "y");

    Expression propExp = Expression.Property(tpe, enumtype.GetProperty("Id"));

    MethodInfo innermethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "Select").First();
    //Error on next line...
    var selectCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
                         "Select",
                         new Type[] { enumtype, typeof(long) },
                         lambda,
                         propExp);
    //TODO: Add rest of logic and actually filter the source
    return source;
}
```

In the `var selectCall =` line I'm getting error:

> No generic method 'Select' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

I've read a lot here on SO and other sites but I can't get past this part, I feel I'm going to bump into more trouble when I get to the `.Intersect(List<int>).Any()` part so any help on that also would be grand, thanks.

Comment: Could you work around all of this using the 'dynamic' keyword?

Comment: @Peter If there is a way to get it done I'm OK about using 'dynamic', can you please elaborate or provide an example. Thanks.

Comment: What is this intersect method trying to do? And why do you _have_ to do it dynamically?

Comment: @khellang The Intersect method is meant to be an extension to the IQueryable<T> object that allows me to filter any entity by any of it's navigation properties by intersecting it's Ids with a list<int>, that is why it needs to be dynamic, because it has to apply to any entity I need to filter. Also, the Intersect method is part of a set of extensions I've created to manage dynamic queries, so the source object could be further filtered. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Sure, but why does it have to be as dynamic as parsing strings? You could still achieve the same thing in a strongly typed fashion?

Comment: The path to the deep property comes from a custom attribute set on a property of a DTO, so even if I send it strongly typed to my Intersect<T> function I would still need to figure out the property  and it's path at run time before calling the extension. Do you think the problem is because of the way I'm creating the deep property expression? I though that was working OK. Is there other way you recommend on how to configure the path of the deep property at DTO level? I used a string because I think complex types are not allowed in attributes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of thought, investigation and attempts I came up with a solution.

First, I made a simpler version of my goal query (the static example I used in my question), so instead of:

```
var res = dbContext.Set<DT_Det_Tr>()
                .Where
                (x => x.TrParent.DataTypes
                    .Select(t => t.Id)
                        .Intersect(_vals)
                            .Any()
                );
```

I made this:

```
var res = dbContext.Set<DT_Det_Tr>()
 .Where
 (x => x.TrParent.DataTypes
         .Any(y => _vals.Contains(y.Id))
 );
```

Which is a lot easier to translate to expressions (or at least it was for me) because it omits the Select call.

I got rid of the method I was using to create the deep navigation property expression and streamlined it in my Intersect function, this was because it was doing some work I don't really need here plus I needed access to some of the variables I use inside it, then I made this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Intersect<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string property, IEnumerable<int> value)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var _value = Expression.Constant(value); //List of ids
    //Declare parameter for outer lambda
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");

    //Outer Lambda
    Expression expr = param;
    foreach (string prop in property.Split('.')) //Dig for deep property
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop);
        expr = Expression.Property(expr, pi);
        type = pi.PropertyType;
    }

    //Get deep property's type
    var enumtype = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    //Declare parameter for inner lambda
    ParameterExpression tpe = Expression.Parameter(enumtype, "y");

    //Inner Collection lambda logic
    //Property for inner lambda
    Expression propExp = Expression.Property(tpe, enumtype.GetProperty("Id"));
    //Contains method call .Contains(y.Id)
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { propExp.Type }, _value, propExp);
    //Create Expression<Func<enumtype, bool>>
    var innerDelegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(enumtype, typeof(bool));
    //Create Inner lambda y => _vals.Contains(y.Id)
    var innerFunction = Expression.Lambda(innerDelegateType, containsMethodExp, tpe);
    //Get Any method info
    var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).Single().MakeGenericMethod(enumtype);
    //Call Any with inner function .Any(y => _vals.Contains(y.Id))
    var outerFunction = Expression.Call(anyMethod, expr, innerFunction);
    //Call Where
    MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call
    (
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { source.ElementType },
        source.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(outerFunction, new ParameterExpression[] { param })
    );
    //Create and return query
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression);
}
```

I hope this helps anyone trying to develop a similar solution.

Working with expression trees can be very hard and frustrating at first, but it's a really powerful tool once you get the hold of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the dynamic keyword from c# 4.0, you might be able to work around the problem like this:

```
var _vals = new List<int>();
var res = dbContext.Set<DT_Det_Tr>()
            .Where(obj => { dynamic x = obj;
               return x.TrParent.DataTypes
                .Select(t => t.Id)
                    .Intersect(_vals)
                        .Any();
                 }
            );
```

But I don't know enough about the details of the problem you want to solve to say for sure.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe my question is not clear, I need to create an extension method to IQueryable<T> that allows me to create the predicate of the example query I gave in my question, so x.TrParent.DataTypes is just an example, I can't use any static types, everything has to be determined at run time. I'll edit my question to be more clear on this. Thanks.

Comment: But what do you know at runtime?

Comment: At runtime I know the type of the entity I need to filter because it is specified in Intersect<T>, also I know the entity is supposed to have a navigation property which is an Enumerable and can be found following the path provided in the "string property" parameter, also I know the Key field of the navigation property will be "(int)Id". That is why I need to create the predicate at run time, because the query is user generated and the Intersect<T> method could responsible of creating just part of it.